# wx.ProgressDialog disappears

Tags: python, wxpython, progressdialog

The progress dialog disappers rather then the *cancel* button changing to a *close* button when it is to be destroyed (and the `PD_AUTO_HIDE` flag is *not* set).

```
    progressDlg = wx.ProgressDialog("Organizing music files",
                                        "This may take some time..",
                                        maximum=9999,
                                        parent=self,
                                        style = wx.PD_CAN_ABORT
                                        |wx.PD_APP_MODAL
                                        |wx.PD_ELAPSED_TIME)
                                        )

    progressDlg.SetSize((400, 200))
    while self.working:
        wx.MilliSleep(250)
        progressDlg.Pulse(os.getcwd())
    progressDlg.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Destroy() explicitly deletes the actual control. I'm pretty sure Destroy()ing a progressdialog behaves as every other control

Comment: A progressDialog should not delete until the close button is clicked (unless the PD_AUTO_HIDE flag is set), the example in the wxpython demos works like this, the only real difference between the demo code and the above is that the above is updated in indeterminate mode...